# Why so low Prediction Rate 25 - 40 [sec/1] using Faster RCNN for custom object detection on GPU?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, object-detection

I have trained a `faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco` model (available [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md)) for custom object Detection.

For prediction, I used object detection demo [jupyter notebook file](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb) on my images. Also checked the time consumed on each step and found that **`sess.run`** was taking all the time.

But it takes around **25-40 [sec] to predict** an image of (3000 x 2000) pixel size ( around 1-2 [MB] ) on GPU.

**Can anyone figure out the problem here?**

I have performed profiling, link to download [profiling file](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/forchetan/Sachin_Support_Docs_Object_Detection/Tensorflow_Profiler.rar)

Link to full [profiling](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/forchetan/Sachin_Support_Docs_Object_Detection/Full_Profilling_Tensorflow_Object_Detection.zip)

**System information:**
Training and Prediction on **Virtual Machine** created in **Azure portal** with Standard_NV6 (details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sizes-gpu)) which uses **NVIDIA Tesla M60** GPU

- OS Platform and Distribution - **Windows 10**
- TensorFlow installed from - Using pip `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu`
- TensorFlow version - **1.8.0**
- Python version - **3.6.5**
- GPU/CPU - **GPU**
- CUDA/cuDNN version - **CUDA 9/cuDNN 7**

Comment: There is no problem, your image is much bigger than the ones that are usually used (around 300x300 to 600x600). So naturally it is slower.

Comment: Hi Matias Valdenegro, I had also tried this with smaller images (less than 600*600, few Kb to max 100 KB size) but the prediction took approx 20 seconds

Comment: Even on large image prediction should be very fast as here you simply apply the function (model). Two things to check: 
(1) Confirm that tensorflow is actually using GPU 
(2) Profile tensorflow, follow e.g. https://towardsdatascience.com/howto-profile-tensorflow-1a49fb18073d

Comment: BTW, as evidenced here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/n-series-driver-setup the VM does not have by default drivers & CUDA installed, so unless you completed these steps, your tensorflow will run on CPU - and it will take considerably longer than on GPU.

Comment: Hi Lukasz Tracewski, it makes sense that prediction on the larger image should not take more than a couple of seconds though mine takes around 15 secs on smaller images.
  (1)   I have performed the profiling(thanks for the tutorial link), but I'm not able to infer anything from it. Can you have a look at it, [link to download profiling file](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/forchetan/Sachin_Support_Docs_Object_Detection/Tensorflow_Profiler.rar)     (2)  Yes I have completed steps to install CUDA and cuDNN

Comment: That's what we need. Profiling info clearly shows that you are using GPU... and that it takes 1.5 second - and that's reasonable. Have a look yourself: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CsrV6YkIyQ9KYtgoS6YLePxTgPXOxGmM You can get the same image if you go to chrome://tracing/ (assuming you have Chrome) and load the file (which you might have done already). Anyway, it's not tensorflow that is stopping you, or at least that's what the data says. I'd recommend to refactor it to a script and run profiling: `python -m cProfile yourscript.py`

Comment: Yes, that's where the mystery begins, as profiling shows it is taking **1.5 secs** but the command **sess.run** itself takes **20+ secs**.

Comment: **Full profiling** can be found [here](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/forchetan/Sachin_Support_Docs_Object_Detection/Full_Profilling_Tensorflow_Object_Detection.zip)

Comment: Hi @SachinPatel, I'm facing exactly the same issue with OID dataset. Did you figure out why sess.run takes so long?

Comment: Not yet @Eran Y

Answer (score 2):

> *Can anyone **figure out the problem** here ?*

### Sorry for being here brutally opened & straight fair
 on
where the root-cause of the observed performance problem is :

One could not find a worse VM-setup from Azure portfolio for such a computing-intense ( performance-**and**-throughput motivated ) task. Simply **could not** - there is no "less" equipped option for this on the menu.

Azure NV6 is explicitly marketed for a benefit of *Virtual Desktop users*, where NVidia **GRID**<sup>(R)</sup> driver delivers a software-layer of services for "sharing" parts of an also virtualised FrameBuffer for image/video ( desktop graphics pixels, max SP endecs ) shared, among teams of users, irrespective of their terminal device ( yet, 15 users at max per either of both on-board GPUs, for which it was specifically explicitly advertised and promoted on Azure as being it's Key Selling Point. NVidia goes even a step father, promoting this device explicitly for *(cit.)* **Office Users**  ).

**M60 lacks** ( ***obviously,*** as having been defined such for the very different market-segment ) **any smart AI / ML / DL / Tensor-processing features**, having **~ 20x lower** DP **performance**, than the AI / ML / DL / Tensor-processing specialised computing GPU devices.

[image]

If I may cite,

> ... "**GRID**" is the **software component that lays over** a given set of **Tesla** ( Currently M10, M6, **M60** ) (and previously Quadro (K1 / K2)) GPUs. In its most basic form (if you can call it that), the GRID software is currently for creating FrameBuffer profiles **when using the GPUs in "Graphics" mode**, which allows users to share a portion of the GPUs FrameBuffer whilst accessing the same physical GPU.

and

> **No,** the M10, M6 and **M60** are **not** specifically suited for AI. However, they ***will*** work, **just not as efficiently** as other GPUs. NVIDIA creates specific GPUs for specific workloads and industry (technological) areas of use, as each area has different requirements.<sub>( credits go to BJones )</sub>

Next,
if indeed willing to spend efforts on this a-priori known worst option á la Carte :

> make sure that **both** GPUs are **in "Compute"** mode, **NOT "Graphics"** if you're playing with AI. You ***can*** do that using the Linux Boot Utility you'll get with the correct M60 driver package after you've registered for the evaluation. <sub>( credits go again to BJones )</sub>

which obviously does not seem to have such an option for a non-Linux / Azure-operated Virtualised-access devices.

---

### Resumé :

If striving for an increased performance-**and**-throughput, **best choose another, AI / ML / DL / Tensor-processing equipped GPU-device**, where both problem-specific computing-hardware resources were put and there are no software-layers ( no GRID, or at least a disable-option easily available ), that would in any sense **block** achieving such advanced levels of GPU-processing performance.

Comment: All true about VM, but according to [profiling file](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/forchetan/Sachin_Support_Docs_Object_Detection/Tensorflow_Profiler.rar) which viewed in chrome tracing it showed the process took around 1500 ms.

Answer (score 1):

As the website says the image size should be **600x600** and the code ran on Nvidia GeForce GTX TITAN X card. But first **please make sure your code** is actually running on **GPU** and **not on CPU**.  I suggest running your code and opening another window to see GPU utilization using command below and see if anything changes.

```
watch nvidia-smi
```

Comment: The trace shows that the OP is using GPU. Moreover, the actual prediction takes ~1.5s, somewhat contradicting the OP statement. Hence request for full profiling,

Answer (score 1):

TensorFlow takes long time for initial setup. ( Don't worry. It is just a one time process ).

Loading the graph is a heavy process. I executed this code in my CPU. It took almost 40 seconds to complete the program.

The time taken for initial set up like loading the graph was 37 seconds.

The actual time taken for performing object detection was 3 seconds, i.e. 1.5 seconds per image.

If I had given 100 images then the total time taken would be 37 + 1.5 * 100. I don't have to load the graph 100 times.

So in your case, if that took 25 [s], then the initial setup would have taken ~ 23-24 [s]. The actual time should be ~ 1-2 [s].

You can verify it in the code. May use the [**`time`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) module in python:

```
import time                          # used to obtain time stamps

for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:  # iteration of images for detection
    # ------------------------------ # begins here
    start = time.time()              # saving current timestamp
    ...
    ...
    ...
    plt.imshow( image_np )
    # ------------------------------ # processing one image ends here

print( 'Time taken',
        time.time() - start          # calculating the time it has taken
        )
```

Comment: Hi Sreeragh A R, Loading graph is not a problem here(time consumed is around 1 sec); as mentioned in the question more than 90% of the time is consumed by **`sess.run`**.

Answer (score 0):

It is natural that big images takes more time. Tensorflow object detection performs well even at lower resolutions like 400*400.

Take a copy of original image, resize it to lower resolution to perform object detection.
You will get bounding box cordinates. Now calculate corresponding bounding box coordinates for your original higher resolutionimage. Draw bounding box on original image.

i.e

Imagine You have an image of 3000*2000,
Make a copy of it and resize it to 300*200.
Performing object detection on the resized image, detected an object with bounding box (50,100,150,150) i.e (ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax)

Now the corresponding box coordinates for larger original image will be (500,1000,1500,1500).Draw rectangle on it.

**Perform detection on small image then draw bounding box on original image.**
Performance will be improved tremendously.

Note: TensorFlow support normalized cordinates.

i.e if you have an image with height 100 and ymin = 50 then normalized ymin is 0.5.
You can map normalized cordinates to image of any dimension just by multiplying with height or width  for y and x cordinates respectively.

I suggest using OpenCV (cv2) for all image processing.

Comment: Hi @Sreeragh A R, thanks for your inputs. Earlier I had tried your suggestion on the image of (3000*3000) and resizing the same image to (300*300) & (400*400), for this smaller image detection took around 15-20 whereas original image took 20+ secs. 

But my concern is why I'm not able to achieve speed closer to claimed [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md). I'm not able to figure out what is missing here.

Comment: Are you getting any warnings like this ? `Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA`            If yes, follow https://github.com/lakshayg/tensorflow-build

Comment: @ Sreeragh A R, No I'm not getting any warnings as my model is created in GPU and Prediction is also on GPU hence no warning for CPU compillations